# I don't understand Jinja2 Call Blocks

Tags: python, jinja2

I understand the concept, but I don't understand the syntax.

I'm going to use the [example](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#macros) used on their site

```
{% macro render_dialog(title, class='dialog') -%}
<div class="{{ class }}">
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    <div class="contents">
        {{ caller() }}
    </div>
</div>
{%- endmacro %}

{% call render_dialog('Hello World') %}
   This is a simple dialog rendered by using a macro and
    a call block.
{% endcall %}
```

What will be the output?

sub-question (because I'm hella confused on how this works): Are you allowed to only have 1 caller per macro?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the output:

```
<div class="dialog">
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
    <div class="contents">

   This is a simple dialog rendered by using a macro and
    a call block.

    </div>
</div>
```

So when we call render_dialog we pass 'Hello World' as title, when it reach `caller()` it passes the contents of the `call` block.

Comment: Cool. Well, what make this different than calling a macro within another macro?

Comment: You can think of a macro as a function in a traditional language. The call block is just an invocation of that function.

Comment: I found that with a nested macro running `caller()` in the nested macro gave an error, since no caller data had been passed to it. What I actually wanted was the data passed to the parent macro. I was able to get at this by, in the outer macro, doing `{% set content = caller() %}` and then in the inner macro using `{{ content }}`.